# Hadoop: Restart failed maps

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm testing the fault tolerance of map reduce.
I found that if I stop the network service in one of the task node, the tasks assigned to this node will be re-assgined to other nodes. That's very good.

However, if the mapper throws exceptions (ex: error access some local resource), the MR job will complete without re-assigning the failed task to other node.

Is there any way that can make Hadoop re-assign the failed tasks to other nodes? Maybe throw some specified exceptions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From which method is the Task throwing the exception?

In case, if you are throwing the exception from TaskUmbilicalProtocol.done() method, you may try another approach.

You can try overriding TaskUmbilicalProtocol.fatalError() method to throw an exception.